# JSON response into database

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, ms-access

Ok, I have tried several kinds of solutions recommended by others on this site and other sited. However, I can't get it work as I would like it to do.

I get a XML-response which I normalize and then save to a CSV. This first part works fine.
Instead of saving it to CSV I would like to save it into an existing table in an access database. The second part below:

- Would like to use an existing table instead of creating a new one
- The result is not separated with ";" into different columns. Everything ends up in the same column not separated, see image below

```py
response = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()
dp = pd.json_normalize(response,'Units')
response_list.append(dp)

export = pd.concat(response_list)
export.to_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Python Scripts\Test\Test2_'+str(now)+'.csv', index=False, sep=';',encoding='utf-8')

access_path = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Python Scripts\Test\Test_db.accdb"
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={};" \
                     .format(access_path))
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO projects2 FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=sep(;);" + \
         "Database=C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Test].Testdata.csv;"  

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(strSQL)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I could only format a part of the code but then it prohibited my from post the question. So now it is "formatted" but it looks terrible, sorry for that

Comment: Thanks flakes for the editing making it look pretty!

Comment: Instead of dumping the DataFrame to CSV you could use [sqlalchemy-access](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access) to push the DataFrame to an Access table using `df.to_sql(… , if_exists="append")`.

Comment: Gord, can you help me with the code for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the data in a well-formed pandas DataFrame then you don't really need to dump it to a CSV file; you can use the [sqlalchemy-access](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access) dialect to push the data directly into an Access table using pandas' [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import urllib

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_string = (
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
    r"ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;"
)
connection_uri = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # existing data in table
    pprint(
        conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM user_table")).fetchall(), width=30
    )
    """
    [('gord', 'gord@example.com'),
     ('jennifer', 'jennifer@example.com')]
    """

# DataFrame to insert
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("newdev", "newdev@example.com"),
        ("newerdev", "newerdev@example.com"),
    ],
    columns=["username", "email"],
)

df.to_sql("user_table", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # updated table
    pprint(
        conn.execute(sa.text("SELECT * FROM user_table")).fetchall(), width=30
    )
    """
    [('gord', 'gord@example.com'),
     ('jennifer', 'jennifer@example.com'),
     ('newdev', 'newdev@example.com'),
     ('newerdev', 'newerdev@example.com')]
    """
```

*(Disclosure: I am currently the maintainer of the sqlalchemy-access dialect.)*

Comment: Thanks Gord. I just solved it by the answer to my own question. However I ran into a new problem which seems to be discussed at several places.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following code

```
SE_export_Tuple = list(zip(SE_export.Name,SE_export.URL,SE_export.ImageUrl,......,SE_export.ID))

print(SE_export_Tuple)

access_path = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Python Scripts\Test\Test_db.accdb"


conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={};" \
                      .format(access_path))

cursor = conn.cursor()
mySql_insert_query="INSERT INTO Temp_table (UnitName,URL,ImageUrl,.......,ID) VALUES (?,?,?,......,?)"
cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query,SE_export_Tuple)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

However, when I add many fields I get an error at "executemany", saying:
cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query,SE_export_Tuple)

Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type  (67) (SQLBindParameter)')